# How can I bind BehaviorSubject's property value to let-* of ng-template?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, ng-template

I've **offset** value stored in BehaviorSubject as shown below.

```
pagingVariables$: BehaviorSubject<QueryPagingVariables> = new BehaviorSubject({
    offset: 0,
    limit: 10
});
```

How can I pass it to ng-template with let-* syntax?

I've tried below code and got **SyntaxError: Unexpected token (**

```
<ng-template let-pageSize="(pagingVariables$ | async)?.offset" ...
```

---

**Edit:** (Modified version of Sebastian's answer)

Thanks [@Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/865695/sebastian). [Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47073147/2215563) gave the idea. But I got "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." with the code shown at answer. Here's how I changed it:

```
<div *ngIf="(pagingVariables$ | async)?.offset as pageSize">
    <ng-template let-pageSize="pageSize" ...
```

---

Alternative solutions (if it's possible without wrapping into *ngIf) are apprecited...

Comment: where you call the `subscribe` and  `next`? 
You could got `pagingVariables$.next()` and set your next return the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate the ng-template in a div (or ng-container) like this:

```
<div *ngIf="{pagingVar: pagingVariables$ | async} as data">
   <ng-template let-pageSize="data.pagingVar?.offset">
   </ng-template>
</div>
```